# URL encoded links in RSS breaks links

Tags: xml, rss, urlencode

In order to have a valid XML RSS feed, I need to url encode my links which contain '&' in the query string.  However, when a person views the RSS feed in a browser, the links are not decoded, so when they click on the link the resulting page is broken because the query string parameters are not being read correctly.

E.g.

http://www.mysite.com?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2, when viewed in the browser as http://www.mysite.com?foo1=bar1%26foo2=bar2, the parameter foo1 is being taken as bar1%26foo2=bar2 instead of splitting fruit and drink into two separate parameters.

Wrapping my links in  tags and not encoding them work, but then in my MRSS feed I have fields such as  where including a  tag breaks the XML.

How can I go about correctly encoding my links so that everything works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

use `&amp;amp`

**Long answer**

If you look at https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/xml, the entry for this question looks like so and your sample link works fine when viewed in I.E.

**Your sample link**

`http://www.mysite.com?foo1=bar1&amp;amp;foo2=bar2`

**Your entry**

```
<entry>
        <id>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705246/url-encoded-links-in-rss-breaks-links</id>
        <re:rank scheme="http://stackoverflow.com">0</re:rank>
        <title type="text">URL encoded links in RSS breaks links</title>
        <category scheme="https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/xml/tags" term="xml"/><category scheme="https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/xml/tags" term="rss"/><category scheme="https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/xml/tags" term="urlencode"/>
        <author>
            <name>Choy</name>
            <uri>https://stackoverflow.com/users/252529</uri>
        </author>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705246/url-encoded-links-in-rss-breaks-links" />
        <published>2011-04-18T15:30:11Z</published>
        <updated>2011-04-18T15:35:43Z</updated>
        <summary type="html">
            &lt;p&gt;In order to have a valid XML RSS feed, I need to url encode my links which contain &#39;&amp;amp;&#39; in the query string.  However, when a person views the RSS feed in a browser, the links are not decoded, so when they click on the link the resulting page is broken because the query string parameters are not being read correctly.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;E.g.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.mysite.com?foo1=bar1&amp;amp;foo2=bar2&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;http://www.mysite.com?foo1=bar1&amp;amp;foo2=bar2&lt;/a&gt;, when viewed in the browser as &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.mysite.com?foo1=bar1%26foo2=bar2&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;http://www.mysite.com?foo1=bar1%26foo2=bar2&lt;/a&gt;, the parameter foo1 is being taken as bar1%26foo2=bar2 instead of splitting fruit and drink into two separate parameters.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;Wrapping my links in  tags and not encoding them work, but then in my MRSS feed I have fields such as  where including a  tag breaks the XML.&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;How can I go about correctly encoding my links so that everything works?&lt;/p&gt;

        </summary>
    </entry>
```

Comment: Interesting, that did the trick!  However, only &amp; is needed, &amp;amp; just produces an extra amp; in the link.  Thanks!

Comment: I have used "&amp;" instead of "&" and it works nice . thanx.

Comment: I have the same problem as @Choy does. To generate a valid RSS document, I need to escape the links which include "&". However, either Firefox and Thunderbird, which are common RSS aggregators, cannot decode/convert "&amp;" to "&" to make the links right.
For examples:
In RSS document, the link looks like
`<link>
https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biomodels/content/model-of-the-month?year=2017&amp;amp;month=05
</link>`
but we need the clickable link likes:
`<link>
https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biomodels/content/model-of-the-month?year=2017&month=05
</link>`

Comment: I just tried https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/url in firefox 60.3.0. It contains a question "Javascript Split URL Lvl Hardcore" In it is a link that has a clickable link that is encoded with &amp;amp (when I view the source). Maybe you have a different issue. If so, a question makes more sense.